# Job started with MapReduce gets killed .Why?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, oozie

i try for several days to start a wordount(MapReduce) job with Oozie. With normal(CMD: "hadoop jar *.jar mainClass input output") job start all things goes just fine . Current oozie configuration is :

- /ApplicationDIR/lib/WordCount.jar
- /ApplicationDIR/workflow.xml
- /Text-IN
- /Text-OUT

  workflow.xml

  ```
  <action name='wordcount'>
      <map-reduce>
          <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
          <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
          <prepare>
              <delete path="${outputDir}" />
          </prepare>
          <configuration>

              <property>
                  <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                  <value>${queueName}</value>
              </property>
              <property>
                  <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                  <value>HadoopJobs.wordCound.WordCountMR.Map</value>
              </property>
              <property>
                  <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                  <value>HadoopJobs.wordCound.WordCountMR.Reduce</value>
              </property>
              <property>
                  <name>mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir</name>
                  <value>${inputDir}</value>
              </property>
              <property>
                  <name>mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir</name>
                  <value>${outputDir}</value>
              </property>
          </configuration>
      </map-reduce>
      <ok to='end'/>
      <error to='kill'/>
  </action>

  <kill name='kill'>
      <message>ERROR: [${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
  </kill>

  <end name='end'/>
  ```

job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://192.168.1.110:8020    
jobTracker=192.168.1.110:8050
queueName=default

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/tmp/testDIR/wordcount-example/ApplicationDIR
inputDir=hdfs://192.168.1.110:8020/tmp/testDIR/wordcount-example/Text-IN
outputDir=hdfs://192.168.1.110:8020/tmp/testDIR/wordcount-example/Text-OUT
```

Command :

```
oozie job -oozie http://192.168.1.110:11000/oozie/ -config job.properties -run
```

RESULT:

[Job gets killed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J66ZC.png)

**--UPDATE--**

> *Oozie Log:*
>   https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BKnv4dSEscRqpzKLhOjUaryveSP3q0454uL_5_xVPdk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share the oozie logs and the job tracker logs

Comment: @KSNidhin i've added Oozie logs . I also check them but nothing special. Could you tell me where i can find JobTracker logs?

Comment: For that You have to Open JT UI and search the JOB Action IF which you will get from OOZIE UI it self, and check with Analysis TAB for getting Job Tracker Job, or You can manually Search for JOB id in Local mapred data.dir location for details of error

Comment: Or use YARN command-line: `yarn application -status application_1454700174038_0001` then `yarn logs -applicationId application_1454700174038_0001` *(side note: the "job" prefix is a legacy thing, YARN now uses "application")*

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by downloading the Cloudera CDH . They have HUE , which has a very nice UI and there i can see my errors in detail. Overall , i solve my error when i delete from workflow xml the following part:

```
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                <value>HadoopJobs.wordCound.WordCountMR.Map</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                <value>HadoopJobs.wordCound.WordCountMR.Reduce</value>
            </property>
```